# Store depths in a 3-D array - HDF5 - Fortran

Tags: arrays, time, 3d, fortran, hdf5

I want to store variables (depth, velocity magnitude and others) in a 3-d array by yValueIndex,xValueIndex,TimeIndex such that each YxX slice would represent something similar to a raster, the null values has to be in the non-assigned areas of the rectangular 2-d dataset. I would like to have something like this:

[image]

My code is in fortran. I do not have too much experience with HDF5. Can somebody help me to identify the HDF5 functions that I need to call? Maybe if someone has an example to share... that will help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Let's make your issue more precise :-) If I understand well, you have several fields defined in a 2D space. A storage strategy is to use a shape of `[Nx,Ny,Nvar]` where Nvar is the sum of all variables degrees of freedom. For instance, for depth (scalar), velocity (2D vector) Nvar=3. In the case of stacking with time as the first axis, that would be `[Ntime,Nx,Ny,Nvar]`. If that is the type of info you are looking for I'll elaborate in a full reply.

Comment: Hello Pierre, that is exactly the issue that I have. I am working in Fortran. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is similar to what I do routinely to store trajectories in molecular dynamics.

You can see an example here: https://github.com/pdebuyl/fortran_h5md/blob/master/h5md_module.f90

What you need to look at `h5md_element_create_time_d3` to create the dataset. What this routine does is create a dataset with dimension `(Nvar, Ndim2, Ndim1, 0)` where the last dimension has an infinite maximum length. The dataset can thus be reshaped at will to add "time frames".

In `h5md_element_append_d3`, the dataset is extended by one in the "time" dimension and filled with the new data.

The routines above also include extra datasets to store an integer time step and the real-valued time. They are also overloaded and bound to a derived type object for convenience.

Beware that HDF5 stores data in C order. For efficiency and intelligibility you need to work with reversed dimensions.

The documentation is only found as an example at https://github.com/pdebuyl/fortran_h5md/blob/master/examples/create_simple_trajectory.f90

The code is licensed under the 3-clause BSD, so you are free to reuse it directly provided attribution is given.